# What is the difference between catch and catchError in RxJS. And How to handle the network error returned by API call?

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

```
mergeMap( (action)=>{

        const data = action.data;
        console.log(state$.value,'\n',action.data);
```

Calling API here. How to handle the network error returned by this call?

```
from(axios.post('http://localhost:3000/addContactIntoDirectory', 
    {directoryId: state$.value.reducer1.SelectedDirectory, contact: data.contact})
))
```

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#howto-convert-to-pipe-syntax

Comment: So, both are same. Just, the name is changed from catch to catchError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically, in RXJS `catch` and `catchError` is identical. You can refer the documentation [RxJs catch/catchError](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html) for more info. Docs also states that we have to return `observable` from `catchError`.
have a look at the given example related to your library `axios` context,

```
axios.post('/formulas/create', { name: "Atul", parts: "Mishra" }) 
.then(response => { 
    console.log(response) 
}).catch(error => { 
    console.log(error.response) 
});
```

Comment: Fine. But, can we use it to handle the network error returned by api call?

Comment: Here is you can go with `axios.post('/formulas/create', {
 name: "",
 parts: ""
})
.then(response => { 
 console.log(response)
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response)
});`

Comment: In this case `axios` returns the error itself, you just have to handle it in `catch` callback.

Comment: or we can do 
`axios.post('/formulas/create', { name: "Atul", parts: "Mishra" }).then(
  null, 
  error => alert(error) // shows "Error: Network error"
);`